# Java process memory Keeps Rising

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

my production Env:

```
OS: windows server 2008 R2 64bit
JDK: 1.6u41 64bit
JBoss: 5.1.0
RAM: 24GB
```

JVM parameters in JBoss as below:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms3072M -Xmx3072M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:NewSize=1024M -XX:MaxNewSize=1024M -XX:SurvivorRatio=32"
```

then I found the java.exe memory usage(private working set)  in windows task manager keeping going up, after few hours reachs to 6GB, then after a few days, reachs to 20GB, then my JBoss server stop working.

I wonder why the memory usage can far beyond the jvm xmx setting?

can someone kindly help me for this?

---

```
FULL GC infomation as below:
C:\Users\Administrator>jstat -gcoldcapacity 2456
OGCMN       OGCMX        OGC         OC       YGC   FGC    FGCT     GCT
2097152.0   2097152.0   2097152.0   2097152.0 20565  1959 3746.986 11586.727
```

Comment: Do you have anything logging verbose GC output? That could be interesting. My guess is that it's a leak in *native* code rather than the managed heap.

Comment: Possibly also a PermGen leak. Sloppy reflection can do that.

Comment: The jconsole shows that the managed heap is always less then 3GB. I check the Jboss logs and cann't find any out of memory error.

Comment: Do you use `ThreadLocals`? You could cause memory leak with redeployment.

Comment: Hi Milan, No ThreadLocal in my code. in Jconsole, the non-heap memory always around 150MB.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why the memory usage can far beyond the jvm xmx setting?

The -Xmx setting *just* gives the maximum size of the Java heap.  Java uses other memory apart from the heap; e.g. the code of the JVM, and memory segments containing compiled code, thread stacks, and memory mapped files.

It seems like your application has a serious memory leak, and that it is leaking non-heap memory.

Comment: Hi, Stephen, thanks for your answer. My app is a web application, using hibernate and spring, some DAOs use JDBC. No JNI code in my app.

Comment: @Justin - there are other things that could cause a non-heap memory leak.  I suggest that you use the normal techniques for tracking down a memory leak.

Comment: What exactly you mean by non-heap memory leak @StephenC when Justin said in the comment above that non-heap memory is always around 150M. For that matter I have kind of similar set of behaviour with noin-heap memory showing 50M close while Window Task Manager shows 350M in memory set. What can be the reason for such a high memory set? Heap is also close to 40M.

Comment: @manocha_ak - It sounds like there is non-heap memory that jconsole doesn't know about.  It would certainly be easier for jconsole to lose track of non-heap memory than heap memory ... based on how these things are implemented.  (But hey, can >>you<< think of a more plausible explanation?)